# Легально ли произвольное название тегов?

Tags: javascript, html, css

## Легально ли создавать теги с произвольным названием

```html
<style>
  sct {
    display table-row;
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>


<script>
  document.createElement('sct');
</script>
<!--Поддержка ie-->
<sct>somecontent</sct>
<!--Тег произвольного названия-->
```

**Почему мне это так важно**
Иногда можно запутаться когда читаешь код, неудобно смотреть на `<div class = "sct"></div>` 
Я знаю, что есть комментарии чтобы не запутаться, но просто очень интересно. Работает даже на дедушке `ie6`, когда я прохожу валидацию кода, это выскакивает как ошибка. Один вопрос, будет ли влиять на работу сайта если я буду использовать это вместо например `div`?

Comment: Может быть, проверить валидатором?

Comment: [Are custom elements valid HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9845011/2881286)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перевод статьи [Are custom elements valid HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9845124/5275890) на русский язык:

Спецификация [Пользовательские элементы](https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/) доступна в Chrome и Opera, и вскоре станет доступна в [других браузерах](http://caniuse.com/#feat=custom-elements). Она предоставляет средства для регистрации пользовательских элементов в официальном порядке.

> Пользовательские элементы - это новые типы элементов DOM, которые могут
>   быть определены автором кода. В отличии от [декораторов](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-components-intro-20130606/#decorator-section), которые не имеют
>   состояния и недолговременны, пользовательские элементы могут
>   инкапсулировать состояния и предоставлять интерфейсы скриптов.

Пользовательские элементы являются частью большей спецификации W3, называемой веб-компонентами ([Web Components](https://www.w3.org/standards/techs/components#w3c_all)), вместе с шаблонами, HTML-импортом и Shadow DOM.

> Веб-компоненты позволяют авторам веб-приложений определять виджеты с
>   уровнем визуальной насыщенности и интерактивности, которые не
>   представляется возможными только с помощью CSS, а также легкость компоновки. 
>   Но повторное использование невозможно с библиотеками скриптов в настоящее время.

Тем не менее, [из этой статьи](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/customelements) Google-разработчиков о пользовательских элементах говорится:

> Имя пользовательского элемента должно содержать тире (`-`). Таким
>   образом `<x-tags>`, `<my-element>` и `<my-awesome-app>` все это
>   действительные имена, в то время как `<tabs>` и `<foo_bar>` - нет. Это
>   требование заключается в том, чтобы анализатор HTML мог различать
>   пользовательские элементы от обычных элементов. Это также обеспечивает
>   прямую совместимость, когда новые теги добавляются в HTML.

Дополнительные ссылки:

- [A "gallery" of Web Components is being compiled](https://www.webcomponents.org/)
- [WebComponents.js](https://www.webcomponents.org/polyfills/) для Web Components, они пока не поддерживаются повсеместно. Смотрите также [WebComponents.js github page & web browser support table.](https://github.com/WebComponents/webcomponentsjs)

Ссылка на источник SO: [Are custom elements valid HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9845124/5275890) (Вопрос 2012 года) Исходя из вышесказанного можно прийти к логичному выводу: *это возможно и допускается*.